# Number of subgroups of finite abelian p-groups with a certain cotype.

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

Given a finite abelian $p$-group $G$ of rank $r$ I'm looking for the number of elements in a group $H$ with $\mathrm{rk}(H)=r$, such that $H/\langle y\rangle\cong G$.

Comment: The number will depend on the group H, and not just on its rank (which can be $rk(G)$ or $rk(G)+1$).

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95233/hall-polynomial-when-the-subgroup-is-cyclic/95478#95478 may help.